# CFLoop Error For Missing Entries

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

**please disregard this post. I have made a clearer example of my problem here:
[Error with CFLoop When Entries Are Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321272/error-with-cfloop-when-entries-are-missing)**

I am running the CFLoop code below.

```
<cfset data = queryNew("sid,firstname,lastname,age","integer,varchar,varchar,integer")>
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="50">
    <cfset queryAddRow(data)>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"sid",x)>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"firstname","#first[x]#")>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"lastname","#last[x]#")>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"age","#studentage[x]#")>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput query="data">
    #sid# -  #firstnamet# #lastname# - #age#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

The variables `first[x]`, `last[x]`, and `studentage[x]` are being pulled from an external datasource, with `X` being the loop index. Note that the CFLoop has 50 entries.

When there is data available, the code works beautifully. However, when there is missing data, the code breaks. By that I mean if Entry 11 doesn't have a name listed for the `first[x]` variable I get an error along the lines of `"Element first is undefined. The error occurred on line 5`

(line 5 is the entry for first name).

When this happens, I would like to omit entry 11 (and all other entries which cause an error) from my results and prevent the error from showing. How can I do this?

**Clarification:** Please assume the data is defined. It gets a bit hairy since I am using an external datasource. But what I am saying is that Entries 1 to 10 show up. When its entry 11's turn, that's when the error comes up.

Comment: Where are the first, last and studentage variables defined?  It appears to me you are creating a query that has 50 rows of identical data.  Also, you are looping over the "data" query, but then displaying the first, last and studentage variables instead of the actual columns in the query which are firstname, lastname, and age.

Comment: OK, I see what is happening.  You are trying to populate the query w/ a variable that isn't defined.  The error is happening on the querySetCell call for firstname not on the the line within the cfoutput.  It has nothing to do w/ a row in the query having no data, it has to do w/ the fact that you haven't defined "first", "last" or "studentage" but you are trying to use their values to populate the query.

Comment: thanks for your reply Sean. those variables are defined, i just did not include it the above code snippet. So what I am saying is Entries 1 to 10 will show up, for example, but than Entry 11 will have the first name missing and then the CF error will pop up.

Comment: OK, but you aren't changing the value of "first", "last" and "studentage" as you loop from 1 to 50, so you will end up w/ a query of 50 rows with the same data in every row with the exception of the sid column which will have 1 through 50.  Can you cfdump the query right after the </cfloop>?

Comment: sorry, this is my fault. I have made a better example, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321272/error-with-cfloop-when-entries-are-missing

Answer (score 1):

Using the recordcount of the external database in the loop should prevent the errors.

```
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#ExternalDatabaseQuery.RecordCount#">
```

A better solution, assuming you do have the query in memory, would be to use a query of queries.

```
<cfquery dbtype='query' name='data'>
SELECT SID, First AS FirstName, Last AS LastName, Age AS StudentAge
FROM ExternalDatabaseQuery
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am not using a database. My external datasource is an XML feed. I have tried a similar approach to the #ExternalDatabaseQuery.RecordCount# before, but the problem is the first 10 entries have a first name, last name, and student age, but when I get to entry 11 there is a last name, age, but no first name. Then entry 12 has all the information again, but the CFLoop gets stuck at entry 11 because of the missing first name

Comment: Check for the existance of the variable then.<cfif ! ArrayIsDefined( 'FirstName', x )><cfcontinue /></cfif>. Can check for each variable or even just put in a blank when it's not defined, etc. Lot of options depending on how you want to proceed.

Comment: Also if you're not using an actual database, you want want to refine your original question, since you say you're using an external database, when in fact you're looping over something quite different.

Comment: sorry, this is my fault. I have given you an upvote for thanks and made a better example, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321272/error-with-cfloop-when-entries-are-missing

Answer (score 1):

Mike, apologies if I'm misunderstanding what you're after but it would seem that some basic conditionals could do the job. The following edit to your code is just a suggestion as to how to go about it (your full code base may dictate something slightly different, of course).

```
<cfset data = queryNew("sid,firstname,lastname,age","integer,varchar,varchar,integer")>
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="50">
    <cfif isDefined("first[x]") AND isDefined("last[x]") AND isDefined("studentage[x]")>
    <cfset queryAddRow(data)>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"sid",x)>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"firstname","#first[x]#")>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"lastname","#last[x]#")>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"age","#studentage[x]#")>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput query="data">
    #sid# -  #firstnamet# #lastname# - #age#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

The primary problem here (and maybe this is not an issue for you) is that this will output 50 - errors. So, if there are 3 errors (i.e., no data found) you'll have 47 entries output rather than 50. If that's an issue, please add a comment ... there are some alternative approaches for ensuring that you always have 50 items output.

Comment: sorry, this is my fault. I have given you an upvote for thanks and made a better example, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321272/error-with-cfloop-when-entries-are-missing

Comment: No worries, Mike! Will check out the new question.